# A question regarding dot product

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, products

I'm struggling to prove that a (dot product) b < |a| |b| .
I have to prove this algebraically and I can't use the equation of dot product involving the cosine.

I wrote each side in terms of the vector components and then squared each side.

Any help would be amazing!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of the case that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are 2-dimensional vectors, for the sake of simplicity of notation.
Let's write their components as $\vec{a} = (a_x, a_y)$ and $\vec{b} = (b_x, b_y)$.
Proceed as you described in your question, and note that
\begin{equation}
a_y^2 b_x^2 - 2a_x a_y b_x b_y + a_x^2 b_y^2 
= (b_x a_y -a_x b_y)^2
\geq 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: how come you are getting a minus sign in that formula?

Comment: $|\vec{a}|^2 |\vec{b}|^2 \geq (\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2 $ is equivalent to $|\vec{a}|^2 |\vec{b}|^2 - |(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2 \geq 0$. The latter can be verified by noting the inequality I wrote.